# Meaning of 『肉』 when used stand-alone, apparently as some sort of insult

Tags: meaning, translation, kanji

I am currently translating an English text, which itself has been translated from an originally Japanese text. Whenever there's something I don't understand in the English text, I try to translate the Japanese original directly into my target language (German).

However, in this case I don't understand what either version is supposed to mean.

Context: video game, on examining an election poster defaced by the rival party

Japanese original: **額に『肉』と書かれている。**

English translation: **Someone has scrawled "MEAT" across his forehead.**

The English translation seems close enough, but I don't understand what it *means*. It's obviously intended as an insult, but what does 肉 mean when used on its own in this context? Is it a generic insult  like e.g. "meathead", "idiot" etc. or does it have a more specific meaning? Or is it perhaps some sort of pun on a homophone?

**UPDATE:** Thank you all for your replies. Since I believe this would be lost in translation otherwise, I decided to go with a less literal translation: "*His portrait is covered with childish scribbles.*"

Comment: Maybe its in reference to [キン肉マン](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/kinnikuman/images/5/55/Kin_Kinnikuman_4.png/revision/latest?cb=20190620150803) , not an insult.

Comment: Are you asking why "MEAT" is scrawled on his forehead? I am not sure that is a question about Japanese. Plus it couldn't be answered out of context. Or are you asking what 「額に『肉』と書かれている」literally means? It just means what the English translation says.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40727/9831

Comment: Drawing 肉 on the forehead of someone is a time-honored meme/prank. https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E9%A1%8D%E3%81%AB%E8%82%89

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a prank that is an imitation of キン肉マン. キン肉マン was a popular manga in the 80's. The main character of the manga is キン肉マン, who has a kanji "肉" on his forehead.